# DB with similar records arrange them to a single record with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which looks like this:

| ID | Description | Type | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Entry 1 | A | Low |
| 1 | Entry 1 | B | Med |
| 1 | Entry 1 | C | High |
| 2 | Entry 2 | A | Low |
| 2 | Entry 2 | B | Med |
| 2 | Entry 2 | C | High |
| 3 | Entry 3 | A | Low |
| 3 | Entry 3 | B | Med |
| 3 | Entry 3 | C | High |

As this is waste of space I would like to reformat the table that it looks like this:

| ID | Description | Type A | Type B | Type C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Entry 1 | Low | Med | High |
| 2 | Entry 2 | Low | Med | High |
| 3 | Entry 3 | Low | Med | High |

So all records with the same ID should be one record and each different type should be a column and it is possible that new types are added to the table in the future. The status should be the value of the type field. Can this be done with SQL?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

Is it possible to add the type columns by it's values so that if a new type has been added to the table no need is to adapt the SQL query? It's a PostgreSQL DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pivoting logic, we can try:

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    Description,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'A' THEN Status END) AS TypeA,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'B' THEN Status END) AS TypeB,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'C' THEN Status END) AS TypeC
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    ID,
    Description;
```

Comment: Perfect it works! Is it possible to add the type columns by it's values so that if a new type has been added to the table no need is to adapt the SQL query? This would be awesome if possible!

Comment: @knox That would require a dynamic pivot, whose syntax is highly database vendor specific.  You never even tagged your question with an actual database.

Comment: Wasn't sure but I checked it and it is a PostgreSQL DB. So you know the syntax for this type of DBs?

Comment: Maybe it's relevant but the type value can be something like 'AB.3' which isn't allowed as column name so far I know!